# Order of words in sentence

Tags: grammar, adverbs, word-order

I am asked the following the question:

> **Question: Why are your results important?**
>
> **Answer:**
>
> 1. For segmenting and classifying a stream of documents dynamically without a fixed training dataset
> 2. For segmenting and dynamically classifying document streams without a fixed training dataset

Which answer is correct to you? Grammatically, the word *dynamically* is intended to be related to *classifying* not *segmenting.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are grammatical, but in your first version, *dynamically* **can** be interpreted as referring to *segmenting* as well. The sentence is ambiguous.

So in order to avoid misinterpretation, your second sentence is much better.

Comment: In fact, 1 is not even ambiguous. It only allows the unintended reading.